# send text-field's value to google as search query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way I can get the value of an input-field and send that to Google as a search query ?

How I would go about doing this would be using jQuery's .attr() and storing that in a variable. Then replacing all the spaces in that string with pluses (+). Then attaching that to http://google.com/? and then navigating yo the newly constructed URL using window.location.

Is there a better way to do this?

Or, if you can not think of a better way, could you help me implement the above.
The parts I am having trouble with are using .attr() and giving window.location a variable as its argument / parametre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, replacing spaces with `+` need not be done as it does not make your query any different.

For the rest, you can use:

```
window.location.href = 'http://google.com?q='+encodeUriComponent($('#textbox').val());
```

Comment: This seems perfect, but it also doesn't seem to work. The value of the input field is being dynamically inserted with jQuery. I put the code below after the code that dynamically inserts the query into the text-field, but the page never goes to google.
`window.location.href = 'http://google.com?q='+encodeUriComponent($('input[type="search"]').val());`